# How to programmatically update a plugin's settings?

Tags: plugin-development

Is there a way to programatically update a plugin's settings? I'm experimenting with [setSettings()](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/etc/plugins/BasePlugin#setSettings-detail) but not really getting anywhere - I'm still quite new to plugin development so there's a good chance i'm completely off target hehe.

For some context: I'm trying to update the plugin settings when an event is fired and picked up by a listener as follows:

```
public function init()
{

    // add event listeners
    craft()->on('assets.onReplaceFile', function(Event $event) {

        //Load Asset
        $asset = $event->params['asset'];

        //Check if asset is the svg sprite
        if($asset->getUrl() == $this->getSettings()->spritePath){
            $url = craft()->getSiteUrl().$this->getSettings()->spritePath;
            $this->setSettings(array('spriteDefs'=>$this->getSpriteDefs($url)));
        }

    });
}
```

getSpriteDefs returns an array.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried a couple of `die()` statements to see if it's making it into your `if` statements?

Comment: Yes it was updating the settings model but not saving it to the db as mentioned in the selected answer below. My question might not have been 100% clear, apologies for that. thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not 100% clear from your question, but I'm guessing that by "update the settings" you mean actually storing the new settings in the database, which the `setSettings()` method will not do; it will only update your plugin's settings model. This means that any following calls to e.g. `getSettingsHtml()` should return the updated data, but it will not persist.

To store the new settings in the database, you'll need to use Craft's [PluginService](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/PluginsService#savePluginSettings-detail):

```
craft()->plugins->savePluginSettings( $this, array( 'spriteDefs' => $this->getSpriteDefs( $url ) ) );
```

The `$this` variable in the call above refers to an instance of [BasePlugin](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/etc/plugins/BasePlugin) – meaning that the above code will only work if called from your plugins main class. I notice that your code is contained within your plugin's `init()` method, so you should be fine, however if you ever want to update a plugin's settings from outside the main class (e.g. through a service), you would first need to fetch an instance of the plugin:

```
$myPlugin = craft()->plugins->getPlugin( 'myPluginHandle' );
craft()->plugins->savePluginSettings( $myPlugin, $settings );
```

Comment: Yes thats correct, by update I meant persist - that is the correct term, sorry for the ambiguity - and I'm calling it within the plugin's main class yes. The savePluginsSettings did the trick :)

Comment: No worries – temporarily manipulating the settings model within the app session lifetime cycle would be a valid use case as well, where ```setSettings``` would be the answer. Happy to hear my answer helped you out!